# Changing color using .on Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Why this code not working?

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ending Project</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="events.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click">
    <h1>Changing</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

The Javascript code:

```
    $("input").on("click" , function(){
    $("h1").css("background-color" , "black");
});
```

I trying to change the background color when I click the button
but it not working and I am doing it like the documentation says!

Comment: because that's not a button. That's an input. Try using `<button>Click</button` or `$('input[type="button"')`

Comment: You are binding the event to a button. There is no button in your html

Comment: Okay. I Changed it but also not working

Comment: DOMContentLoaded. `$(function () { $("input").on("click" , function() { $("h1").css("background-color" , "black"); }); })`. Put your code inside `$(function() { /* your code */ })`.

Comment: @AhmedA.Talawy do you have JQuery included? Where is this JavaScript located? What error do you get?

Comment: You're running your code before the elements exist in the page. You need to wrap your jQuery in a document.ready call or move it to the end of the page

Comment: @AhmedA.Talawy Did you read my comment? I told you, fixing the selector is only the first step.

Comment: @dfsq .. yeah it fix the problem..Good Work Pro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view it has 2 options, I do not know which one is the best.

First, as it says "dfsq" put your code inside a   function

```
<input type="button" value="Click">
<h1>Changing</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input").on("click", function () {
            $("h1").css("background-color", "black");
        });
    });
</script>
```

or second create a function and call it from the input

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeColor()" value="Click">
<h1>Changing</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(){
        $("h1").css("background-color", "black");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "put your code inside a function" is not what that example does to fix the problem - if you pass a function to jQuery, it'll call it as a DOM ready callback: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ending Project</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click">
    <h1>Changing</h1>
    <script src="./events.js"></script>

</body>
```

Putting the script tag at the end of the body intrinsically wait for your DOM to be loaded before running the script. This is how I would do it.
FYI, in modern browser there's [defer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer) so the following would also work

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ending Project</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./events.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click">
    <h1>Changing</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes it should. But explain why.

Comment: Added some info , for the interested

Answer (score 0):

You either need to select the element using input selector or use html tag button

```js
//If using input type button then use input selector
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
  $("h1").css("background-color", "black");
});

// or use button selector 
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("h1").css("background-color", "green");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click">
<h1>Changing</h1>


<button type="button" value="Click">Button</button>
<h1>New Button</h1>
```

Comment: I think the OPs issue is that the the event handler is being added before the DOM is ready, not that the selector is wrong.

Comment: no the problem was that i need to put the JavaScript code after the HTML code

Comment: @SpoonMeiser  yeah

Comment: @SpoonMeiser he edited the question, initially it was `$("button").on("click", function() {...` but there was no button tag present